# Searching data through a specific Field in C# from MS Access db using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access-2016, icsharpcode

I am working on a project and i have to perform a task in that project that i have to print/find data from a MS Access Database 2016 File through a specific  text or keyword i'll try everything but can't solve my problem so after trying everything i decided to post my problem here to get some help to solve it.
I attached my code you can see that but that code doesn't performing any thing and i got a error while try to search anything the error is

> A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

This is the error I am facing while perfroming the task.

```
namespace Vechile_Registration_System
{
public partial class Verification : Form
{
    public Verification()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Verification_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchDataBase();
    }
    private void searchDataBase()
    {
        string strsearch = txtsearch.Text.Trim().ToString();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        vehicleBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("[Registration No] LIKE '%{0}%'", strsearch);

        string strFilter = sb.ToString();
        vehicleBindingSource.Filter = strFilter;

        if (vehicleBindingSource.Count != 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = vehicleBindingSource;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Records Found. \n The Vehcile may not register or you have enter wrong Registration Number.");
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 MMenu = new Form1();
        MMenu.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211395/discussion-on-question-by-sk-hassan-searching-data-through-a-specific-field-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLEASE READ CAREFULLY:

1. You've deleted a very important line and because of this, no data is being loaded into your data source.

We are making the first change in Verification.cs file. Change the Verification_Load exactly like this:

```
    private void Verification_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vehicleTableAdapter.Fill(vehicleDataSet.Vehicle);
        // If you want the grid view to show no data at the beginning
        // Uncomment the following line
        // vehicleBindingSource.Filter = "1 = 0";
    }
```

2. You've somehow managed to remove the searchbutton_Click event handler.

Please apply these steps exactly as they are suggesting:

- In the solution explorer double click the Verification.cs. This should open the form in design mode.
- On the form, right click the SEARCH button and select Properties from the menu.
- In the Properties window at the top, there are some icons. Find the "Events" icon with a thunderbolt (lightning) shape. Click this.
- Now, at the very top, there is the "Click" event.
- Be very careful with typing and enter `btnsearch_Click`

And that's all.

Hope this helps.

Please mark as answer if it does

---

---

**** ORIGINAL ANSWER ****

This should solve your problem.

Please use exactly this code.

```
private void searchDataBase()
{
    string strsearch = txtsearch.Text.Trim().ToString();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    vehicleBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("[Registration No] LIKE '%{0}%'", strsearch);

    if (vehicleBindingSource.Count != 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = vehicleBindingSource;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Records Found. \n The Vehcile may not register or you have enter wrong Registration Number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This Code doesn't solve my issue and now the code is not generating any output when i click on search button.

Comment: Can you upload your solution smoewhere so I can fix?

Comment: Just sent you a message on chat in which i attach a **link** from where you can download the `solution`. If you `fix` it let me know through Chat.

Comment: I am updating my answer. Please check the top of it. You've made mistakes, and I will show you how to fix it there. Please mark as answer if it fixes it (It is working for me right now. Searches and can find and display the record)